# ProFTPd won't accept users after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

So I set up an extremely basic proftpd server the other month. Today, I rebooted the server and it simply won't accept any type of connections. I feel like there had to have been something that I disabled to allow these connections (this is the first time I've rebooted).

Here's what a conection using filezilla looks like:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.2c Server (S*****r) [::ffff:12.30.***.***]
Command:    USER ld**i
Response:   331 Password required for ld**i
Command:    PASS ****
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Even if I try to connect locally:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
220 ProFTPD 1.3.2c Server (S*****r) [::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Name (localhost:root): c****e
331 Password required for c****e
Password:
421 Login Timeout (300 seconds): closing control connection
Login failed.
No control connection for command: No such file or directory
```

proftpd.log shows this, but nothing to signify a "closing".

```
 Feb 15 12:19:45 ubuntu proftpd[7127] ubuntu.localdomain(::ffff:10.199.30.88[::ffff:10.199.30.88]): FTP session opened.
```

Account still doesn't work! These are all definitively working accounts that we have been using for months at this point. Any clue what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you had your firewall disabled? Is it running now?

Comment: I had assumed that there was no built in firewall on ubuntu? At least there was no iptables running on the server.

Comment: There is! Check https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/firewall.html .

Comment: yes, but this is disabled by default. Also, it doesn't seem to be a firewall issue because I can't connect by running 'ftp localhost'